# How to stop MediaPlayer Framework then FlipView changed?

Tags: windows-runtime, media-player

I have **mmppf:MediaPlayer** inside **DataTemplate** in **FlipView** on **ItemDetailPage.xaml**.
When i start video on current item and go to next or prev flip, video of prev item continue playing. How to stop video of current then user change selected item in flipview?
I trying to stop it in **FlipView_OnSelectionChanged** method, but i can't get access to control.
How can i stop playing video of previous element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like that :

```
var container = MyFlipView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(previousIndex) as FrameworkElement;
var mediaPlayer = container.FindName("MyMediaPlayer") as MediaPlayer;
```

Then you have access to all methods and properties of MediaPlayer

Comment: In your sample MyMediaPlayer - is it x:Name of mmppf:MediaPlayer?  container.FindName("MyMediaPlayer") as MediaPlayer  is null in my case (

Comment: yep ! you have to add x:Name="MyMediaPlayer"

Comment: Do you know method how to right get previousIndex? ок how to determine direction in flipview (to right or to left)? thanks a lot!

Comment: Hey, you can do something like that :
http://pastebin.com/7wRDiugH
Just use PreviousIndex property to know where the flipview comes from